# Table structure change To Responsive?

Tags: jquery, css, html, responsive-design

i have used code like this table view how to change its div tag style ?
 i  want to change table structure  in responsive ? how to i will change any idea?   can i use style inside of table tag ? i have tired in div tag but its not working ? any idea how to change this structure   full responsive ??

```
<TABLE BORDER="1" id="login" CELLPADDING="4" CELLSPACING="0">
 <TR>

        <TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><FONT FACE="VERDANA" SIZE="2"><B>Organization ID:</TD>

        <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="org_id"></TD>

      </TR> 
<TR>

        <TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><FONT FACE="VERDANA" SIZE="2"><B>UserName:</TD>

        <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="uname"></TD>

      </TR>

      <TR>

        <TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><FONT FACE="VERDANA" SIZE="2"><B>Password:</TD>

        <TD><INPUT TYPE="password" NAME="pwd"></TD>

      </TR>

      <TR>

        <TD COLSPAN="2" ALIGN="RIGHT"><INPUT TYPE="IMAGE" SRC="images/login.png" BORDER="0"></TD>

      </TR>

    </TABLE>

    </FORM>
```

Comment: Can you add this in a jsfiddle so it will be better for us to help.

Comment: i have added in jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/pqp1pbcn/

Answer (score 0):

set table width in percentage

```css
table{
  width:100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `<TABLE BORDER="1" id="login" CELLPADDING="4" CELLSPACING="0" width="100%">`

Answer (score 0):

You can write both html tags( Table login and Div style login), keep div login hided and use media queries to show it and hide table when displaying in smaller sizes.

something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<style>
    .div-login{
        display: none;
    }
    .table-login{
        display: block;
    }
     @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        .div-login{
            display: block;
        }
        .table-login{
            display: none;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

 <div class='table-login'>
    <form action='destination.php' method='post'>
        <strong> write your table-styled form here </strong>
        <!-- <table> </table> -->
    </form>
 </div>
 <div class='div-login'>
    <form action='destination.php' method='post'>
        <strong> write your div-styled form here </strong>
        <!-- <div> </div> -->
    </form>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```